# Why do some users have a blank avatar?

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture

I have noticed that some users are getting a bluish Gravatar which looks like the following:

[jee](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/234123/jee)

[image: Bluish Gravatar-1]

[Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/248054/clara-diaz-sanchez?__=1969705761)

[image: Bluish Gravatar-2]

[Riya](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/251912/riya)

[image: Bluish Gravatar-3]

Is this intentional or just a bug?

Comment: You probably will need to specify what device your using the access those gravatars.  On the web, [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) doesn't look like that.

Comment: Also, share a link to specific users, so others can verify/falsify

Comment: @Rebbecca I am using mobile site

Comment: Ah, I can reproduce... via the browser, not the app.

Comment: It's blank due to missing Google profile picture, already reported in the past.

Answer (score 8):

When I visit those user profiles on the main site, [their profile image returns a 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kybq.png).

The ones I checked were all hosted by Google on the lh[3|5|6].googleusercontent.com domain. It could be that there is a temporary outage or that the user decided to remove that image / deleted their Google account or Google stopped offering the service.

This is a 3rd-party problem and not something Stack Exchange, or you for that matter, can fix.

If this is permanent the impacted users need to take action, for example by uploading a new profile image, preferable into the imgur instance of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Would it be an issue if they didn't take action and just left the profile image blank?

Comment: @DanK No, I don't think that is an issue. At best it is confusing. You could argue that maybe SE should fallback to a generated avatar but I think it is hard to determine if the 404 is temporary or permanent.

Comment: @rene also hard (and expensive) to catch broken image in server side, currently SE just throw what Google gives as the profile picture without checking it. Client side fallback is possible (using `onerror` JS event) but it's hacky and not elegant. All in all, IMHO better leave it as it is now.